# .NET Core Website bindingRedirect Build Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When building an ASP .NET Core web app on our local machines we have no problems however we get bad App.exe.configs when we build on a build server (2012 R2) using a VSTS build agent.  All environments have VS2015 Update 3 installed and the latest version of the .NET Core Tools - Preview 2.  When we build locally we get the following config.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.2.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.37.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.Metadata" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.4.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.2.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

On the build server we get...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.Metadata" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.4.1.0" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.37.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

First question is why so many more entries?  But the main issue is two items have incorrect version numbers as shown below which is causing errors.  Any advice or ideas on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

and

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: What's the result if you build the project on that build machine (server 12 R2) manually? What're build steps of your build definition? Can you share detail build log here?

Comment: Can you share a simple project on the OneDrive, which can reproduce that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why so many packages?

before: all the system.* dlls where part of the dotnet framework. now its part of the Dotnet Standard library, which you download from nuget: and thus so many assemblies.

For the binding redirect i have no clue. One solution i can think of is that dotnet tries to restore these dependencies. but other dependencies you use say that they 'Must' have version 1.0.0.0 of these packages. Then Nuget is so kind to give you that package instead of the 1.0.0.0 one. (It should give a warning on restore though)

sidenote: i still vote for the way more simple project.json version of dotnet core sdk. i still mourn its upcomming death.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joel.  Yeah we had seen posts online mentioning about other dependencies requiring specific versions.  Strange thing is it works when we build locally and when we correct the version numbers manually it works fine.  Also shouldn't our local build produce an app.config with the same number of dependantAssembly elements?